# Get value from jsonb_array

Tags: postgresql

How can I get values of array in my jsonb type column named 'body' in order to use the value to join another table.
example:-

```
SELECT U.* 
from masters."USERS" as U
    left join masters."ROLE" R on U.body->'role' = R.id
```

Below is my column data.

```
{
    "live": "0",
    "role": [
        "1"
    ],
    "desig": "",
    "email": "chandan@logibricks.in",
    "empCode": "",
    "mobileNo": "",
    "password": "$2a$10$qDENcVR/ZDFIsp/blXK7h.h4xsmI18/LArvbqmtNfXxZ6jYO/s5YG",
    "userName": "chandan",
    "full_name": "Chandan ",
    "department": "",
    "updated_by": "rhlsoni",
    "is_access_results": "1",
    "updated_timestamp": 1550556834,
    "reporting_manager_id": "",
    "is_access_testscripts": "1",
    "is_access_workingpapers": "1"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand the array using jsonb_array_elements_text() with a lateral join in this way:

```
select 
    users.id, 
    role.name
from   
    users
join lateral 
    jsonb_array_elements_text(data->'role') r on true
left join 
    role
    on role.id = r.value::int
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=0686e677d28c6f93e376fcf8fe399974)*